# Same viewController on both iOS and tvOS apps, UIPickerViewDelegate not available on tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I am using a ViewController for both iOS and tvOS targets and for iOS I use a UIPickerView.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController,
    UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, 
    UITextFieldDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate,
    UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate
```

The UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate are not available on tvOS, and I'm only using them on iOS, but I get the error *UIPickerViewDelegate is unavailable* when I try to build for tvOS.

Is there a way to include UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate only for iOS app and exclude them when building for tvOS?

Answer (score 2):

this is one way to do it

```
class Test : UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate{

}
#if os(iOS)
extension Test : UIPickerViewDelegate{
    //delegate code goes here!   
}
#endif
```

but if you need the delegate code to be inside the class i would recommend to to make a super class without the UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate and add it in the sub class

```
 SuperFirstViewController
           |
           |
           /\
          /  \
         /    \
        /      \
      tvOS    iOS - FirstViewController
```

or in code

```
class Test : ViewController{
    //some code..
}
class iOSTest : Test, UIPickerViewDelegate{
    //some code..
}
class tvOSTest : Test{
    //some code..
}
```